# How to run Get Kusto Query using Rest API

Tags: powershell, rest, azure-data-explorer, kql

Can someone help me frame the REST API call to Kusto Cluster to get results for a basic Kusto Query.

As per this [Kusto Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/api/rest/request#get-query-parameters), We need to send the Query as a parameter. Can someone please give me an example? The documentation has examples only for POST Calls which i was able to figureout. But now, i need to do GET calls as well to fetch data from Kusto tables.

Below is my sample REST API Call to Kusto. can someone please tell me where and how to pass the Kusto query below?

```html
$accessToken = (Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceUrl "https://MyKustoClusterName.westus2.kusto.windows.net").Token

$authHeader = @{
        'Content-Type'='application/json'
        'Authorization'='Bearer ' + $accessToken
        'Host'='MyKustoClusterName.westus2.kusto.windows.net'
        }

$Query = MyTableName | project column1, column2, column3

$Uri = "https://MyKustoClusterName.westus2.kusto.windows.net/v2/rest/query"
$Response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Uri -Method GET -Headers $authHeader -Query???
```

Comment: I believe you need to pass the json having a `query` property in the body of your request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**note:** it's probably much simpler to invoke the .NET libraries from powershell, instead of authoring your own code for constructing and sending a request, then parsing the response.

- see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/api/powershell/powershell

---

the request body is documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/api/rest/request

there's also an example at the bottom, that uses `curl` (which you should easily be able to use as-is, or 'translate' to using the `Invoke-WebRequest`, if you prefer the syntax of the latter)

the sample body provided in that document is as follows (and matches the query `print Test="Hello, World!"`, running against a database named `Samples`):

```json
{
  "db":"Samples",
  "csl":"print Test=\"Hello, World!\"",
  "properties":"{\"Options\":{\"queryconsistency\":\"strongconsistency\"},\"Parameters\":{},\"ClientRequestId\":\"MyApp.Query;e9f884e4-90f0-404a-8e8b-01d883023bf1\"}"
}
```

Comment: Ok I had to use POST and it completed without any errors. Now, How to fetch the rows from the response?

Comment: I think I got the results. I just need ot trim the response a bit but $Response.Columns and 
$Response.Rows has everything I need. 

Thanks a ton @Yoni.